# Split a big Photoshop file

Tags: adobe-photoshop, file-size

I'm working on a big Photoshop file. With time, it will get bigger and bigger, until my system won't be able to handle it. The image is a RPG map, and I oversized things a little to fit everything I wanted into.

Is there a way to split a portion of all the layers at the same time, so I can save and edit it as another file, without merging/flattening everything, so preserving the layers (text, vectors, effects, etc)?

Comment: Would simply saving the file, then duplicating it in the OS..  and then continue working on the duplicate... work?

Comment: It is already eating 6,5 GB of my RAM (I have 16)... I really need is to split it, so it will consume less resources...

Comment: But you could save it, duplicate it, open the duplicate, remove everything not needed and save again. The duplicate will then be smaller.

Comment: Or maybe you could convert specific sections of it into embedded smart objects and convert them into linked smart objects after the fact.

Comment: That's an idea. I'll try.

Comment: Not sure if it works in your case but it helped me ago; all i did was splitting psd into little pieces and then placing all those psd as linked in my main psd. use **file-place linked**; but make sure you'll have to keep linked PSDs safe. I didn't tried place embedded though :D